# How can draw gradient on UserControl added in form in c#?

Tags: c#

When Form loaded will add UserControls 2 columns and multi rows

To show recently added data

The number of rows depending on the height of the screen.

The number of columns depending on the width of the screen

```
if ((int)count_columns == 2)
{
    for (int sp = 0; sp <= (int)count_rows; sp++)
    {
        //add UserControl
        latest latest1 = new latest();
        latest1.Name = String.Concat("latest1_", sp.ToString());
        latest1.Left = (leftPanel.Width + (int)space_between_columns);
        latest1.Top = ((topPanel.Height + (32 * sp)) + (latest1.Height * sp)) + 32;
        this.Controls.Add(latest1);

        latest latest2 = new latest();
        latest2.Name = String.Concat("latest2_", sp.ToString());
        latest2.Left = (2 * (int)space_between_columns + latest2.Width + leftPanel.Width);
        latest2.Top = ((topPanel.Height + (32 * sp)) + (latest1.Height * sp)) + 32;
        this.Controls.Add(latest2);
    }
}
```

when tried draw gradient on UserControl

```
private void latest1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen white = new Pen(Color.White);
    var rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 145);
    var brush = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(
                    rec, 
                    Color.FromArgb(255, Color.DarkBlue), 
                    Color.FromArgb(0, Color.DarkBlue), 
                    90f);
    e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half;
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rec);
}
```

nothing happened

Comment: Your code works fine. Maybe the numbers don't fit? Or, more likely, the Paint event is not hooked up??? Add something like `latest1.Paint += latest1_Paint`..

Comment: The code does not set the Size property.  Do not hard-code the Rectangle, use ClientRectangle instead.  Set ResizeRedraw = true in the constructor.  Always favor overriding OnPaint() instead of using the Paint event.